Why does my clock app rings randomly? [Ubuntu 24.04]
Since I started using the timer function in the clock app, the ring sound from when the timer runs out appears randomly, including when a timer is running but has not reached 0, and even with the clock app closed. This stops after a reboot, but I don't know why this happens.
I've read some posts regarding time issues that mentioned dual-boot with Windows, so I'll add that I have Windows 10 in dual boot, if it happens to be related.
Clock app:


It's intended to keep working "even with the clock app closed." It would be unreliable if it could be disabled by accidentally closing the window. People accidentally close windows all the time.
